# What is famous mistake made by Feller?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I heard "Feller made a famous mistake in 1954 and fixed by A.D. Wentell in 1959" from one lecture.   There is no further explain what is that mistake? Is there someone know it? Is it possible to explain a little bit it?

Comment: Why not ask the lecturer?

Comment: Biggest "mistake" by Feller (in the '60s, not in the '50s) was writing the 2nd edition of "An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications, Vol 2" before writing the 1st edition of Vol3, which supposedly would have been on diffusion processes. The guy ups and dies before Vol 3 ever got written.

Comment: It is the recording lecture. Thank you!!

Comment: Can you link to the lecture?

Comment: Sorry,  I tried it but it can not be linked.

Comment: One not-so-famous mistake was Feller's belief that Bayesian inference could not be used in applied statistics. Nobody can think that now and many who were informed on the subject (as Feller was not) did not think that then. Two other amusing oddities are the way in which he refers to Mark Kac in the index and his acknoledgement to Prof. Dennis Hejhal who had written to him, who (Feller did not realize) was a high-school pupil at the time. (Today Hejhal has for some decades been a professor of mathematics.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference, the two papers are

[1] W. Feller. [Diffusion processes in one dimension,](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1954-0063607-6%20) Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. **97**, 1-31 (1954).
[2] A. D. Wentzell. [On boundary conditions for multidimensional diffusion processes,](https://doi.org/10.1137/1104014) Theor. Probability Appl. **4**, 164-177 (1959).

Differential operators with boundary conditions containing diffusion terms were introduced by Feller [1] for one-dimensional diffusion and by Wentzell [2] for higher dimensions.

My best guess to what is going on is that the the lecturer was referring to the limitation to one dimension in Feller's 1954 work, a limitation removed by Wentzell's 1959 paper. I am not aware of any error in [1].

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question; surely it’s only a comment?